# drupal: Create multiple sizes of an image with imagecache

Tags: drupal, image-processing, drupal-6

For a certain nodetype within my drupal6 project I need an image in 3 different sizes (preview, mainview and thumbs). What I would like imagecache to do for me is to create these 3 different sizes from just one upload. Is that possible?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it is possible.

Imagecache creates the images when they are displayed.  So in other words, in the imagecache ui you create your three sizes (preview, main view, and thumbs).

Then wherever you are going to display the image, say using image from filefield in cck, you select the desired size from the drop down.

If your content type is "page" then go to admin/content/node-type/page/display and select your display for both teaser and node.

In a view, you add the field which holds your image (filefield-image) and then choose which size to display.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely. Read this:

http://drupal.org/project/imagecache